# Configure multiple lan interfaces for same subnet on sonicwall

Tags: firewall, local-area-network, sonicwall

We have a sonicwall 2400, Is there any way to assign multiple interfaces to the same lan subnet? Basically, we would like to have X1 for the wan and X0, X2, X3 and X4 connected to 4 devices that would form a lan.

EDIT: We are currently limited in space so adding a switch isn't a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unfamiliar with the 2400 model, but on our SonicWall (a TZ205 running 5.8) we achieve this by adding the interfaces to the LAN Zone and configuring them as a PortShield to the primary LAN interface (X0).  Portshield can/does add some extra security, but effectively treats the interfaces as switch ports on the same network.

This is configured via the `Network -> Interfaces` area, the LAN interface is configured as normal and the "extra" LAN interfaces are set to the LAN zone, PortShield Switch Mode, and PortShield to X0 (our LAN).

```
X0 - LAN
X1 - WAN
X2 - Portshield to X0
X3 - Portshield to X0
X4 - Portshield to X0
```

The [SonicWall admin guides](https://support.software.dell.com/sonicwall-tz-series/release-notes-guides) contain details of the PortShield functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Would it not be more straightforward to purchase a small (i.e. 8-port) switch, and connect X0 to the switch? This is traditionally the more standard way of running the LAN.

Example (port numbers is parentheses):

```
Internet - (X1) SonicWALL (X0) - (1) Switch (2+) - LAN devices
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we are currently limited in space due to colocation. So this isn't a possibility in the short term.

Comment: Ah - in that case, I'm unsure if you can assign multiple ports to the same subnet. You'll need to give each port a different IP (see this image: https://www.fuzeqna.com/sonicwallkb/includes/customer/sonicwallkb/uploadfiles/Image/KBID8220Interface.jpg) - that _should_ work, however it's less than ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your extra interfaces as Layer 2 Bridged Mode.
/Edit - OK, you have found (and I didn't know) that L2BM is limited to 2 interfaces. On other units, you can configure ports as Portshield groups. You can check to see if a newer firmware support Portshield on the device.

Comment: Unfortunately, L@ bridged mode is limited to two lan interfaces.

Comment: Also, I've got a 2600 and  can't get DHCP working with 2 bridge interfaces.